# Macro to go to a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with a lot of sheet tabs, and to make navigating it easier for user's I've added a macro to bring up an input box so that they can type in the sheet they want to go to.

It works but the problem is that if they type in a sheet name incorrectly it does nothing, the input box goes away, and the user is left on the same sheet they were already on. What I would like it to do is if a user types in a sheet name that doesn't exist for it to bring up a box with a list of all the tabs and allow them to choose from the list. Barring that, at least a message box informing them they entered a non-existent sheet name and to try again, and to then go back to the input box rather than it disappearing.  Here's the code I've been working with so far-

If that's not possible, I'd rather have it just bring up a list of available sheets in the first place and forget the input box altogether. My thought was that it would be nice to type in the needed sheet rather than having to sort through the list every time, but it'd be preferable to nothing happening.

```
Sub GotoSheet()
Dim sSheet As String

sSheet = InputBox( _
  Prompt:="Sheet name or number?", _
  Title:="Input Sheet")
On Error Resume Next
If Val(sSheet) > 0 Then
    Worksheets(Val(sSheet)).Activate
Else
    Worksheets(sSheet).Activate
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks all! Looking through these for some options I was able to get what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a list of available sheets to pop up so you can choose one just make a quick UserForm, insert a ListBox (a ComboBox would work as well, I prefer a ListBox visually), and have it populate on userform_initialize:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In Worksheets
        ListBox1.AddItem WS.Name
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Make sure the MultiSelect property is set to 0 for single select then create an ok button that goes to the selected sheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Then create a button or whatever to show the form.

Comment: Agree, cut out the option to search via user string.  Let the user simply select the sheets available.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you and handles all error without the need to use `On Error` statement.

```
Function Validate(SheetName As String) As Boolean
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
If SheetName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name Then
Validate = True
Exit Function
Else
Validate = False
End If
Next
End Function

Sub GotoSheet()
Dim sSheet As String

sSheet = InputBox( _
  Prompt:="Sheet name or number?", _
  Title:="Input Sheet")
Do While Validate(sSheet) = False
'This if statement is true when the user click cancel or x button
If sSheet = "" Then
Exit Do
End If
MsgBox (sSheet & " does not exist. Please enter a valid sheet name.")
sSheet = InputBox( _
  Prompt:="Sheet name or number?", _
  Title:="Input Sheet")
Loop
If sSheet <> "" Then
    Worksheets(sSheet).Activate
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root of your problem at the moment is `On Error Resume Next`. This is causing the sub to simply exit when your else statement encounters an error, such as the sheet does not exist. Instead you need to handle that error through the use of something like `On Error GoTo`. As in:

```
Sub GotoSheet()
Dim sSheet As String

sSheet = InputBox( _
  Prompt:="Sheet name or number?", _
  Title:="Input Sheet")
On Error GoTo noSheet
If Val(sSheet) > 0 Then
    Worksheets(Val(sSheet)).Activate
    Exit Sub
Else
    Worksheets(sSheet).Activate
    Exit Sub
End If 

noSheet:
'Enter your code to display a warning that the sheet does not exist
'and/or bring up a selection box of all sheets

End Sub
```

Here is some more information on the `On Error` statement, which may be of use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173%28v=vs.60%29.aspx